# How to include the logs from the discover page on a Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, dashboard, kibana-5

I was looking through some sample dashboards and i came across this picture:

https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/elastic/uploads/default/original/3X/1/6/169b7101acc60136b3eb4003b11c094b619083c5.png

(last visualisation on the page)

I was wondering if anyone knows how i can include the logs that i can see on the discover page on the dashboard like this example?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Including the answer I got on a different site*

1. Go in the discover tab, on the top right you select "save"
2. Go back to the dashboard, select "add" on the top right
3. Lastly you select the "saved search" tab (next to the "Visualization" tab), you should see what you saved earlier :slight_smile:

Original question link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/include-logs-on-the-dashboard/92243

Can confirm this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**As of 2022:**

1. In Discover - save your search view.
2. In the dashboard when you are in edit mode, click on the "Add from Library" button
3. Search your saved search view and click on it - this will add it to the dashboard.